# Sending a request to a third party server

Tags: node.js, express, webserver

I am trying to mimic what happens when I click a check box on the browser. Basically, I want to have my program send the same request to the third party server that would happen if I was actually on the website doing it myself. I just need some reference to what I can use to do this?

I'm using node.js and express.

When I click a certain entry I get back http://website.com/createOrUpdateEntry?matchup=m57342o543

I have all the specific ids already I just need to find a way to send back that same http request from my server instead of going to the website and doing it manually.

It's on a different website. It just updates the page as a submission.

`Request URL:http://website.com/createOrUpdateEntry?matchup=m5‌​7342o543 Request Method:GET Status Code:302 Found Remote Address:68.71.212.199:80 Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade`

so far I've looked at cURL and the json.post method. I was just trying to figure out how to actually start the process and what I need to use

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please include your code in your question, along with any error messages you may be getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not very clear. From what I understand, you want to send an http request to another server that is not yours. To do you can use this module found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

Comment: Sorry. I'm trying to update a page from my program as if I were doing it through the website. I want the program to be able to run on it's own without me having to go to the actual website and enter the submission myself.

Comment: You need to answer a few questions. Where is this button located. On your website? Where does it lead? What does it do? A get http request? A post http request? What have you tried so far?

Comment: It's on a different website. It just updates the page as a submission. 
                                                                                                            
``Request URL:http://streak.espn.com/en/createOrUpdateEntry?matchup=m57342o543
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Found
Remote Address:68.71.212.199:80
Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade``                                             so far I've looked at cURL and the json.post method. I was just trying to figure out how to actually start the process and what I need to use

Comment: You want to trigger the activation of the button using your nodeJS application? If yes then the module I originally sent should help you achieve that. Sending requests to another server can also be done using nodeJS http module itself